# Is it possible to reduce the number of lines without breaking the logic?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing

I need to make a test - which of the lists is faster. To do this, I run each test in a new thread. I create the runnable method for the each thread in a separate class. I get a rather monotonous code, this is a DRY violation. Maybe someone knows how I can run all threads at the same time without breaking DRY?

```
public class ThreadsManager {

    public static boolean stopThreads = false; //We change this variable MainActivity
    public static long timeOfStartTest = 0;

    public void startCollThreads() {
        stopThreads = false;
        timeOfStartTest = new Date().getTime();
        CollRunnable collRunnable = new CollRunnable();

        new Thread(collRunnable.addBeg(new ArrayList())).start();
        new Thread(collRunnable.addBeg(new LinkedList())).start();
        new Thread(collRunnable.addBeg(new CopyOnWriteArrayList())).start();

        new Thread(collRunnable.addMid(new ArrayList())).start();
        new Thread(collRunnable.addMid(new LinkedList())).start();
        new Thread(collRunnable.addMid(new CopyOnWriteArrayList())).start();

        new Thread(collRunnable.addEnd(new ArrayList())).start();
        new Thread(collRunnable.addEnd(new LinkedList())).start();
        new Thread(collRunnable.addEnd(new CopyOnWriteArrayList())).start();

        new Thread(collRunnable.search(new ArrayList())).start();
        new Thread(collRunnable.search(new LinkedList())).start();
        new Thread(collRunnable.search(new CopyOnWriteArrayList())).start();

        new Thread(collRunnable.removeBeg(new ArrayList())).start();
        new Thread(collRunnable.removeBeg(new LinkedList())).start();
        new Thread(collRunnable.removeBeg(new CopyOnWriteArrayList())).start();

        new Thread(collRunnable.removeMid(new ArrayList())).start();
        new Thread(collRunnable.removeMid(new LinkedList())).start();
        new Thread(collRunnable.removeMid(new CopyOnWriteArrayList())).start();

        new Thread(collRunnable.removeEnd(new ArrayList())).start();
        new Thread(collRunnable.removeEnd(new LinkedList())).start();
        new Thread(collRunnable.removeEnd(new CopyOnWriteArrayList())).start();
    }
}
```

```
public class CollRunnable {

    //region Adding in the beginning
    public Runnable addBeg(List list) {
        return () -> {
            for (int i = 0; i <= elementsNumber; i += 1) {
                if (stopThreads) {
                    return;
                }
                list.add(0, "");
            }
            updateViewModelValue(1,"Adding \nin the beginning", list);
        };
    }
    //endregion

    //region Adding in the middle
    public Runnable addMid(List list) {
        return () -> {
            for (int i = 0; i <= elementsNumber; i += 1) {
                if (stopThreads) {
                    return;
                }
                list.add(0, "");
            }
            updateViewModelValue(2, "Adding \nin the middle", list);
        };
    }
    //endregion

    //region Adding in the end
    public Runnable addEnd(List list) {
        return () -> {
            for (int i = 0; i <= elementsNumber; i += 1) {
                if (stopThreads) {
                    return;
                }
                list.add("");
            }
            updateViewModelValue(3, "Adding \nin the end", list);
        };
    }
    //endregion

    //region Search
    public Runnable search(List list) {
        return () -> {
            list.add(0);

            for (int i = 0; i <= elementsNumber; i += 1) {
                if (stopThreads) {
                    return;
                }
                list.get(0);
            }
            updateViewModelValue(4, "Search \nby value", list);
        };
    }
    //endregion

    //region Removing in the beginning
    public Runnable removeBeg(List list) {
        return () -> {
            for (int i = 0; i <= elementsNumber; i += 1) {
                if (stopThreads) {
                    return;
                }
                list.add("");
                list.remove("");
            }
            updateViewModelValue(5, "Removing \nin the beginning", list);
        };
    }
    //endregion

    //region Removing in the middle
    public Runnable removeMid(List list) {
        return () -> {
            for (int i = 0; i <= elementsNumber; i += 1) {
                if (stopThreads) {
                    return;
                }
                list.add("");
                list.remove("");
            }
            updateViewModelValue(6, "Removing \nin the middle", list);
        };
    }
    //endregion

    //region removing in the end
    public Runnable removeEnd(List list) {
        return () -> {
            for (int i = 0; i <= elementsNumber; i += 1) {
                if (stopThreads) {
                    return;
                }
                list.add("");
                list.remove("");
            }
            updateViewModelValue(7, "Removing \nin the end", list);
        };
    }
    //endregion

    private void updateViewModelValue(int numberOfTest, String testName, List list) {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
            DataClass dataClass = new DataClass(numberOfTest,testName, list, new Date().getTime() - timeOfStartTest);
            getCollInstance().viewModel.testResult.setValue(dataClass);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for the record: starting many threads and checking which one finishes first is **not** a sensible way of benchmarking various approaches to a problem, you'll want to write a proper micro-benchmark, which [can be tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to detach the creation of the list. For example with the help of an interface:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ListFactory {
    List create();
}

    // In ThreadsManager
    public void orquestate() {
        startCollThreads(() -> new ArrayList());
        startCollThreads(() -> new LinkedList());
        startCollThreads(() -> new CopyOnWriteArrayList());
    }

    private void startCollThreads(ListFactory listFactory) {
        stopThreads = false;
        timeOfStartTest = new Date().getTime();
        CollRunnable collRunnable = new CollRunnable();

        new Thread(collRunnable.addBeg(listFactory.create())).start();
        new Thread(collRunnable.addMid(listFactory.create())).start();
        // Other steps
    }
```

It's not exactly the same as the steps are started first for lists types, but I don't know if that is important for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) functional interface. As follows, extract a method that will test a given *function* passed as parameter on the list types:

```
private void run_test(Function<List, Runnable> collRunnable) {
    new Thread(collRunnable.apply(new ArrayList())).start();
    new Thread(collRunnable.apply(new LinkedList())).start();
    new Thread(collRunnable.apply(new CopyOnWriteArrayList())).start();
}
```

and then adapt your `startCollThreads` method:

```
public void startCollThreads() {
    stopThreads = false;
    timeOfStartTest = new Date().getTime();
    CollRunnable collRunnable = new CollRunnable();

    run_test(collRunnable::addBeg);
    run_test(collRunnable::addMid);
    run_test(collRunnable::addEnd);
    run_test(collRunnable::search);
    run_test(collRunnable::removeBeg);
    run_test(collRunnable::removeMid);
    run_test(collRunnable::removeEnd);
}
```

**A side note**

You are using Raw types, you should avoid that, [see this source to see why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

You can make it more generic by also parameterize the list passed as parameter:

```
private void run_test(Function<List, Runnable> collRunnable, Supplier<List>... lists) {
    for (Supplier<List> list : lists) {
        new Thread(collRunnable.apply(list.get())).start();
    }
}
```

then you can called the method with different lists:

```
run_test(collRunnable::addBeg, ArrayList::new, LinkedList::new, CopyOnWriteArrayList::new);
```

or

```
run_test(collRunnable::addBeg, ArrayList::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use thread pool API for this propose. For example [ExecutorService.html.invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-)

For example:

```
   try {
       Runnable routine = (List<?> args) -> { // add your thread routine implementation }
       // you can use same routine for all tasks, or make any combination such as 3 different routines in list etc
       Runnable[] allTasks = new Runnable[8];
       Arrays.fill(allTasks, routine);
       ExecutorService pool =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
       // invoke all tasks from array in thread pool
       pool.invokeAll( Arrays.asList(allTasks) );
       // stop pool and await for it termination
       pool.shutdown();
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
         pool.shutdownNow();
       }
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     pool.shutdownNow();
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
```